# Not able to show icon on browser (chrome)

Tags: jquery-mobile

[image]

Hello

i am implementing header but not able to show header (icon Add and setting). i used jquery mobile add header .in fiddle i am able to see icon but here i am not able to show . can you please help me

```
  <html>
    <head>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">

      <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>



    </head>
    <script>



    </script>
    <body>
      <div data-role="page">
       <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
      <h1 class="ui-title"  id="hdr" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 10px;">My Cases</h1>
      <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> 
      <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b">Edit</a>
     <a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog">Add</a>
     <a href="#newevent1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog">Edit</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Mobile Button Icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809987/jquery-mobile-button-icons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of missing images.
Please make sure that you have the latest jquery files from [here](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.zip) and that you have the `images` folder (provided in zip file) inside the `css` folder ie the folder which contains jQuery Mobile's CSS file.

Comment: How to make dynamically  table in jquery mobile ..?

Comment: That's true @Omar sirji :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have attached `images` folder into folder where is your `jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css` file, it contains some icons that if not sourced correctly will show layout like that only...

Check Whether the icons are their or not...

Sitmap:-

```
css/folder---------jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css/file
css/folder---------images/folder
```

Comment: How to make dynamically table in jquery mobile ..?